# how to access my web app in apache-ubuntu with custom domain name in a LAN?

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu, dns, lan

I have developed a web app using laravel & apache 2.4 in ubuntu 15.04 inside vmware. I have configured ip address of the ubuntu as static which is 192.168.1.250. 
Within ubuntu i can access the web app from ip 127.0.0.1 or localhost. And from the networked devices, i can access it using the ubuntu's ip address 192.168.1.250.
Now, i want to access the web app using a domain name from the networked devices instead of IP address. I think i need to install and configure dns server in ubuntu along with apache. So, i installed BIND dns and tried to configure it but failed. So, if it can be done with BIND, then i was wondering HOW? If not, then what may be another way? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tunnel to your local environment by using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which will give you a temporary address (to keep the address static you have to use pro features a.k.a paid features)

Follow this steps:

- Download ngrok and unzip ngrok
- Open a cmd / terminal and navigate to ngrok location
- Type the following command:

> ngrok http {your_localhost_server_port_number}

- It will create the tunnel but we need to point a virtual host to it so edit your local server virtual host and add an alias / server name like following:

  **NOTE: if you only have one app running on your local server this step is optional**

> *.ngrok.io

- Now restart your local server to load our new configuration
- Now you are able to see your localhost site online by using the ngrok provided url.
- Enjoy!